# How to add together my input results of form data

Tags: javascript, html

How do I create a section below that will post all of the values added together?

```
<p>Your personal financial advisor.</p>
<br />
<p>How much do you may every two weeks?</p>
    <table border= "1px">
        <tr>
            <td><form>
                <input id="quantity" class="qty" type="text" placeholder="quantity" />
<br>
                <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calc"/>
                </form>
                    <script>

                    document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', updater);

                    function updater () {
                        var cost = 2;
                             var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
                                var totalcost = (cost * quantity);

                    document.getElementById('total').innerText = totalcost;
                    }
                    </script>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<p>How much is your rent or mortgage per month?</p>
    <table border= "1px">
        <tr>
            <td><form>
                <input id="mortgage" class="mrg" type="text" placeholder="mortgage" />
<br>
                <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calc2"/>
                </form>
                    <script>

                    document.getElementById('calc2').addEventListener('click', updater);

                    function updater () {
                         var payments = 1;
                            var mortgage = document.getElementById('mortgage').value;
                                var totalcost2 = (payments * mortgage);

                    document.getElementById('total2').innerText = totalcost2;
                    }
                    </script>



            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

Ideally I would like the have a statement here that says "Your total monthly expense are: the total of each of the input values after their calculations are complete. How do I do this?

How do i re-call my output values to create calculation?

Comment: FYI: Aside from your question, you have a bug. You redefine `updater`. I think, but am not certain, that both button clicks are calling the second one.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about what you actually want? Do you want it so that you get the total of how much you make. Then you subtract your expenses?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually have about 4 additional forms that I have returning different outputs at the bottom of this code which was just for preference. I was using a span to return the values just to add additional text but the problem I am having is getting total to add to total 2 and so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: And yes I will be adding and subtracting but I know I can figure out the rest from just learning how to recall those output values.

Comment: You can create a div with a id of totalcost or totalcost2 to see your output or can set them to variables for use later. Also another way is to set the output to a variable and console.log(your variable goes here);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just playing around with your code just to show you how to get the output.
I have a example here at http://jsfiddle.net/davygxyz/3rrb5fqs/2/.

Your personal financial advisor.

How much do you may every two weeks?

```
<form>
    <input id="quantity" class="qty" type="text" placeholder="quantity" />
</form>
```

How much is your rent or mortgage per month?

```
<form>
    <input id="mortgage" class="mrg" type="text" placeholder="mortgage" />
    </form>

    <button id="calc" >Calculate</button>
    <div id='total'></div>

<script>

    document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', updater);

    function updater () {
    //calculate how much the person makes every two weeks.
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    //since your asking for every two weeks, I set a variable below equal to 26 instead of 52.
    var weeks = 26 
    var q_total = quantity * weeks;

    //Rent or mortgage per month

    var months = 12;
    var mortgage = document.getElementById('mortgage').value;
    var yr_mortage = mortgage*months;


 // subtract expenses 

 //Create variable total, takes the total quantity and substract your expenses.
 var total = q_total - yr_mortage;


 document.getElementById('total').innerText = "Your Income is "+q_total+" dollars for the Year. \n Your expense is "+yr_mortage+' dollars for the year.\n All together your funds come to '+total+' dollars.';


//You can console most of your work to check it also. Example:

console.log(yr_mortage,q_total,total);

</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! I have been working on trying to a find an answer to this for quite some time now. Obviously i am just a beginner and primarily just a  recreational coder. From your example i realized that because  all of my variables were not within a single function updater I was unable to recall these for my final calculations. I had each of these separated. This is probably a major reason to keep your javascript separate from your HTML.

Comment: No problem @GodeCurios. I was the same way and I've actually learned a lot by looking at peoples problems on this site. Glad I could help you. It's definitely a good idea to keep them separated, looks clean and somewhat organized.

Comment: @GodeCurios Also, could you do me a favor and cast a up vote. If that answers your question. Thank you ps. Im slacking on the ratings haha